# Sending between two different classes in different packages in Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm developing an App to receive Sms and Send the `Geo-location` to the incoming Phone number. `SMSReceiver` is one class and the other class is `MainActivity`..

`SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`

and

`MainActivity extends Activity`...

Now i want to send the `Phone_number` ( String ) from `SMSReceiver` Class to the `MainActivity..`

Any Ideas? I'm a Beginner in Android Development !!  If you need Code i'll give . Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting a new MainActivity?

If so,

```
String phone = "";
Intent theIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
theIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phone);
startActivity(theIntent);
```

I would not recommend having the broadcast receiver trigger a change in an already running MainActivity. However, if you really want to do it, there are two ways you can manage this.

1. Set your activity in the manifest to be `singleInstance`, override the `onNewIntent()` function and run the same code as before in the Broadcast receiver.
2. Create a content provider/model, have main activity listen to provider/model, update the model when the broadcast receiver is fired. (this is much more complicated)

Comment: When i use the intent in SMSReceiver class. It shows an Error

`The constructor Intent(SMSReceiver, Class<MainActivity>) is undefined SMSReceiver.java 
'